# Build Time Error - FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: angular, angular-universal

My Angular universal project which is quite big in size and even it gets bigger as it goes.

It was configured with **nodesize as 8096 (which is the solution given in most of the similar questions)** which was working upto yesterday, then we added some more modules into our project that breaks the application and gets the heap memory issue back. So we tried increasing the **max_old_space_size to 12286**, changed the **node version to 12.16.1(latest)** but nothing works.

Build Command

```
node --max_old_space_size=12288 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod && ng run server
```

And also I see there are lot of **similar questions** asked in stackoverflow in which many users suggested to use either 4096 or max 8092 but **we are going beyond already**. 
So I have following questions,

> What will happen if we keep the max_old_space_size at max(say some
>   20gb) ?
>
> Is there any other solution apart from increasing the node_size like
>   changing the architecture of the project ?

As of now, My project is not working.

Please throw some light on it.

Thanks for your time. (:

Comment: FYI the size is specified in MB, so 8092 is already 8 GB

Comment: @David Misspelled it. Edited the question.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? For me I noticed that I needed to raise that limit after upgrading to angular 9

Comment: Angular version - 6.1.10 we are using.